# oracle - consumir webservice soap

Tags: oracle, soap, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola al correr un ejemplo de la siguiente pagina 
https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/consuming-web-services-9i

El oracle developer me genera un error con las *acl* que dise lo siguiente:

```
ORA-29273: fallo de la solicitud HTTP
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", línea 1130
ORA-24247: acceso de red denegado por la lista de control de acceso (ACL)
ORA-06512: en "xxxxxx.SOAP_API", línea 150
ORA-06512: en "xxxxx.ADD_NUMBERS", línea 34
         29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
       Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

¿Como puedo resolverlo? ¿Que me recomiendan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero: No entiendo por qué sigues un ejemplo de Oracle 9i si estás usando Oracle 11g.

El error es autoexplicativo. Tienes que construir una lista de control de acceso y asignar dicho permiso al usuario al que deseas permitirle el acceso a recursos externos por HTTP.

En Oracle 11g, usar cualquiera de estos paquetes requiere esa configuración:

```
UTL_TCP
UTL_SMTP
UTL_MAIL
UTL_HTTP
UTL_INADDR
```

Para validar que esa configuración no se ha hecho, uno ejecuta esta consulta:

```
 SELECT * FROM dba_network_acls;
```

La creación de los ACL es un procedimiento con dos pasos. El primer paso es crear la ACL y definir los privilegios a darle. La sintaxis estándar es:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL (
acl => "file_name.xml",
description => "file description",
principal => "user_or_role",
is_grant => TRUE|FALSE,
privilege => "connect|resolve",
start_date => null|timestamp_with_time_zone,
end_date => null|timestamp_with_time_zone);
END;
```

El valor `connect` para el parámetro `privilege` incluye **`resolve!`**, que es necesario para el paquete UTL_INTADDR.

- El parámetro `principal` especifica el primer username que se le asigna la ACL y es case sensitive!
- Si se le quiere asignar a múltiples usuarios, debe usarse el privilegio DBMS_NETWORK_ACL.ADD_PRIVILEGE para añadir usuarios.

Un ejemplo de creación de ACL con datos es:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL (
  acl => 'sysdba-ch-permissions.xml',
  description => "Permissions for sysdba network',
  principal => "LUTZ',
  is_grant => TRUE,
  privilege => 'connect');
END;
```

Esto crea un archivo xml con una lista de usuarios y privilegios. Se ubica bajo `/sys/acl/` en la BD XML. ¿Que cómo supe que usas Oracle 11g? Porque este error no pasa en Oracle 9i, no hay BD XML en 9i y no hay fine-grained access control (control del acceso a recursos externos usando HTTP).

El segundo paso es asignar network hosts a la ACL. La sintaxis estándar es:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL (
acl => "file_name.xml",
host => "network_host",
lower_port => null|port_number,
upper_port => null|port_number);
END;
```

Y un ejemplo con datos:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL (
  acl => 'sysdba-ch-permissions.xml',
  host => "*.sysdba.ch',
  lower_port => 80,
  upper_port => null);
END;
```

Aquí hay que tener en cuenta que:

- Es posible usar wildcards en el parámetro `hosts`. Permite el acceso a todos los hosts en un dominio dado.
- Los Hostnames Son case-sensitive
- Puede usar una IP o un hostname DNS.
- Sólo un ACL puede asignarse a un host o dominio o subnet IP o rango de puertos
- Puede asignar múltiples hosts a la misma ACL invocando DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL múltiples veces.